# How To Fix Boolean Modifier with Python Script

Tags: python, boolean-modifier

[image]
I have this object with holes in the scene, that i want to cut with the bumpy surface, but when i apply boolean modifier with 'Difference', the result is not what i want. As my object is not solid, the boolean modifier just deletes the surface that it is intersected with. But i want my object to get the shape of the bumpy surface in places where they interact. In other words i want the inner part of the object fit perfectly with the bumpy surface.
And i want to do this with python script. I found solidify modifier to fill the object, and then cut with the bumpy surface but when applying it the holes are partially cut. Is there another way?